# Flowbale auditlog

Tags: audit-logging, flowable

I want to audit entire application built in flowable, I am spring boot develeoper, I getting difficult to implement audit log in Flowable. I am looking alike envers in Spring Boot, which audit specific entity annotated upon.

Answer (score 0):

In flowable bpmn, there is facility of event logging. This is disabled by default. If enabled this logs events to database table act_evt_log.
Flowable also provides the facility to add a custom event logger. Using this you can achieve the functionality of auditing.
Reference: [Flowable Event Logging](https://wwv.flowable.com/open-source/docs/bpmn/ch18-Advanced/#event-logging)